# Creating Meteor package library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, module, package

I'm wanting to create a "core" package and "module/plugin" packages much like `accounts-facebook` uses `accounts-base` in Meteor.

Here's what I have currently but it's not working:

*packages/project:modules-core/package.js*:

```
Package.describe({
  name: 'project:modules-core',
    summary: 'Core package for Modules.',
    version: '1.0.0'
});

Package.onUse(function (api) {
    api.versionsFrom('METEOR@0.9.1.1');

    api.addFiles('lib/core.js', ['client', 'server']);

    if (api.export) {
        api.export('HBModule');
    }
});
```

*packages/project:modules-core/lib/core.js*:

```
HBModule = (function () {
  var moduleName = "";

  var getShareCount = (function (url) {

  });

  var register = (function (name) {
    HBModule[name] = name;
  });
}());
```

*packages/project:facebook/package.js*:

```
Package.describe({
  name: 'project:facebook',
    summary: 'Facebook Module.',
    version: '1.0.0'
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
    api.versionsFrom('METEOR@0.9.1.1');

    api.use('project:modules-core', ['client', 'server']);

    api.imply('project:modules-core', ['client', 'server']);

    api.addFiles('lib/facebook.js', ['client', 'server']);
});
```

*packages/project:facebook/lib/facebook.js*:

```
Facebook = (function () {
  var moduleName = "Facebook";

  var getShareCount = (function (url) {
     return 22;
  });
}());

HBModule.register('facebook');
```

And with this I'm getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined` error.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IIFEs (Immediately-Invoked Function Expressions)  aren't returning anything, so `HBModule` and `Facebook` are both undefined. When creating the HBModule, you need to return an object with a `register` property set to your `register` function.

```
HBModule = (function () {
  var moduleName = "";

  var getShareCount = (function (url) {

  });

  var register = (function (name) {
    HBModule[name] = name;
  });

  // return an object that will be assigned to HBModule
  return { register: register };
}());
```

Also the IIFE's are unnecessary here, as Meteor will wrap each file anyway, and only expose the variables you use without declaring (such as `HBModule`); all the variables declared with `var` will be scoped to that file.

*packages/project:modules-core/lib/core.js:*

```
HBModule = {};
var moduleName = '';

// assuming you want to expose the getShareCount method as well?
HBModule.getShareCount = function (url) {

};

HBModule.register = function (name) {
  HBModule[name] = name;
};
```

*packages/project:facebook/lib/facebook.js:*

```
Facebook = {};
var moduleName = 'Facebook';

Facebook.getShareCount = function (url) {
  return 22;
};

HBModule.register('facebook');
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you! One more question, how would I go about making the modules use default functions if one isn't set? For example, if I didn't create a "Facebook.getShareCount" function, it would just use "HBModule.getShareCount" function instead when calling the first function?

Comment: Thanks! There are a variety of ways to do that; I'd recommend using "classes" (prototypal inheritance) as I think it enhances readability. I don't know what version of Meteor you're on, so I'm going to write the example for Meteor 1.3+: (you can do the equivalent in earlier versions of Meteor, but it'll be written somewhat differently). https://gist.github.com/nathantreid/8ef9e734d52b179bee12123ef81b3065